# How do I redirect to another form after submitting a form in django

Tags: django

SO I have the following form which is working.:

```
<body>
    <form method="POST" class = "incubatorBox" novalidate enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}

            <h2 class = "register-text"> Add Incubator</h2>
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <br>
        <input class = "register-button" type="submit" name="" value="Register">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I have the following models.py

```
class Incubators(models.Model):      # These are our database files for the Incubator Portal
    incubator_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    owner = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    city_location = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=100)
    logo = models.FileField()
    verify = models.BooleanField(default = False)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('main:details', kwargs = {'incubator_id': self.pk})

    def __str__(self):                  # Displays the following  stuff when a query is made
      return self.incubator_name + '-' + self.owner 

class Details(models.Model):
    incubator = models.ForeignKey(Incubators, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name='banana_pudding')    
    inc_name = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    inc_img = models.FileField()
    inc_contact = models.CharField(max_length = 600, default = "Enter all available means of contacting")
    inc_details = models.TextField(max_length= 2500)
    inc_address = models.TextField(max_length = 600, default = "Address")
    inc_doc = models.FileField()
    inc_policy = models.FileField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.inc_name
```

So Basically whats happening here is that the first form is adding data in the Incubator database and after submission it has to redirect the user to form which enter the data in Details database in the models.py. My first form is working fine and adding data to the database. But then I am getting an error:

```
DoesNotExist at /incubators/19
Details matching query does not exist.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/incubators/19
Django Version: 2.0.2
Exception Type: DoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
Details matching query does not exist
```

And my views.py look something like this:

```
class AddIncubator(CreateView):
    model = Incubators
    fields = ['incubator_name', 'owner', 'city_location', 'description', 'logo']

class AddIncubatorDetails(CreateView):
    model = Details
    fields = ['incubator_name', 'owner', 'city_location', 'description', 'logo']
```

I want to redirect to the form for adding entries in AddIncubatorDetails()
I have also made a form template for the same. Do let me know if you want me to post that too.\
Below is my urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

app_name = 'main'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^home/', views.home, name='home'),    # Home page
    url(r'incubators/$', views.incubators, name='incubators'),    # Incubator list page
    url(r'about/', views.about, name='about'),          # Websie about page
    url(r'results', views.result, name = 'result'),         # For search function
    url(r'^incubators/(?P<incubator_id>[0-9]+)', views.details, name = 'details'),      # shows details of incubators
    url(r'incubators/add/$', views.AddIncubator.as_view(), name = 'add-incubator'),
    url(r'incubators/add/(?P<incubator_id>[0-9]+)$', views.AddIncubatorDetails.as_view(), name='add-details'),# Adding Inc
]
```

Comment: Could you add the relevant `urls.py` please?

Comment: Do check the edits.

Comment: So what is `views.details`? Your URL /incubators/19 is going to that view, and getting an error that the Details object is not found. Shouldn't that URL be going to a view that queries Incubators, not Details?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in your `urls.py`, specifically this URL:

`url(r'^incubators/(?P<incubator_id>[0-9]+)', views.details, name = 'details'),      # shows details of incubators`

Without seeing `views.details` I can't tell you exactly what the problem is but my suspicion is that you try to lookup the (not yet created) `Details` object in that view.

Django's `CreateView` has `success_url` attribute that tells it what URL to go to on successful submission of the form. By default this will go to the details view for the created object (See: http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.0/django.views.generic.edit/CreateView/#get_success_url)

Whereas I gather you wish to direct them to the `add-details` view. In which case in your CreateView you can define the `success_url` attribute:

```
class AddIncubator(CreateView):
    success_url = reverse_lazy("add-details")
    model = Incubators
    fields = ['incubator_name', 'owner', 'city_location', 'description', 'logo']
```

The site I linked, http://ccbv.co.uk, is incredibly useful for looking up the inner workings of djangos class-based views.